# Firefox will not open (Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware Player)

Tags: firefox, 14.04, lts

Ubuntu is freshly installed under VMware Player for testing. Firefox will not open in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Desktop). There are no instances of firefox running in System Monitor. What can be the reason, and is there a solution?

I have Firefox opened from the terminal.  Problem, I cannot add a screenshot to AskUbuntu (I need at least 10 reputation to post images).

The output:

```
(process:2286): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:2286): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:2286): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:2286): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:2286): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
Kan de Gnome-sneltoetsenmap '/home/ubuntu/.gnome2/accels' niet maken: Toegang geweigerd


"Kan de Gnome-sneltoetsenmap '/home/ubuntu/.gnome2/accels' niet maken: Toegang geweigerd" is Dutch and means "Cannot create the Gnome shortcut directory '/home/ubuntu/.gnome2/accels': Access denied".
```

Comment: Open firefox from terminal and post the output.

Comment: Output from terminal posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a permissions problem: try to change the permissions of the folder by typing:

```
sudo  chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu
sudo  chmod -R 664 /home/ubuntu/.gnome2/accels/
```

You should now be able to open firefox.

Comment: "sudo  chmod -R 664 /home/ubuntu/.gnome2/accels/" is not the solution, the problem and output is the same.

Comment: SOLUTION FOUND : sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu

Comment: having no other information about the permissions on the folder I had supposed that the owner was "ubuntu". I edit my answer adding your command.

Comment: Problem solved, Firefox will open.  Thank you very much for your help girardengo. :-)

Comment: `sudo  chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu`    chown: invalid user: 'ubuntu:ubuntu'    `sudo  chmod -R 664   /home/ubuntu/.gnome2/accels/`    chmod: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/.gnome2/accels/': No such file or directory